# Data not rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a website that displays data in a list that is filterable. When a filter is applied I'd like it to be appended to the URL as a parameter. I have written a service for this:

```
app.factory('urlFilter', ['$location', function ($location) {
    var urlParams = $location.search();
    return function ($scope, myUrlParams) {
        angular.forEach(myUrlParams, function (param) {
            $scope[param] = isset(urlParams[param]) ? urlParams[param] : 0;

            $scope.$watch(param, function (value) {
                if (isset(value)) {
                    $location.search(param, value);
                }
            });
        });
    };
}]);
```

`urlFilter` is the last thing called in the controller:

```
urlFilter($scope, ['company_id']);
```

In a controller I fetch a resource and set the `company_id` on watch. `company_id` is updated using a drop down. Whenever `company_id` is updated I refetch the resource:

```
$scope.$watch('company_id', function (companyId) {
    if (!isset(companyId)) {
        return;
    }

    Api.resource.query({company_id: companyId}, function (data) {
        $scope.resources = data;
    });
});
```

This approach works perfectly on my localhost environment. But whenever I upload it to production it kind of works. If I change the company the resources are requeried and the URL parameter is set correctly. If I refresh the page with a URL parameter in it I see that the resource is requeried, using Chromes debugging tool, with the correct `company_id` and the response is OK. However the view is not updated, i.e. empty resource list and initial no company is set in the company drop down.

**What have I done wrong? Is there a better approach?** I am not using angular routing.

Note: isset() is a function I wrote myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding `parseInt()` when using the values that was gathered from `$location`, i.e:

```
$scope[param] = isset(urlParams[param]) ? parseInt(urlParams[param]) : 0;
```

Comment: Weird thing is that this makes the solution not work on my local environment, but works fine in production.